# Number of digits in $12^{300}$

Tags: logarithms

Given: $\log_{10}2= 0.3010$ and $\log_{10}3=0.4771 $, find the numer of digits in $12^{300}$

Options:  $324,323,325,\text{Other}$

Actually I tried breaking 12 into 2*2*4.. And then tried to guess the series in no of digits increasing per multiplication of a term.. This really doesn't help.. I am not able to find the use of Log in the question.. :/
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 12 = 2*2*3, not 2*2*4.

Comment: Oh sorry that's a typing mistake.. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint:

$$\log_{10}12^{300}=300\log_{10}12=300(\log_{10}2+\log_{10}2+\log_{10}3)$$

Comment: My pleasure, glad to help.